# How can I add a resizable QVBoxLayout in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I add a resizable QVBoxLayout in [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator)?

Demonstration: QVBoxLayout size changed with size in a Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your form, then select "Lay out" => "Lay out vertically".